# would I able to do bidirectional communication between leaf device and Azure IoT hub by using Azure IoT edge gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I want to use Azure IoT edge as an identity translation gateway for my TCP/IP-based device for that I have gone through many documentation regarding Azure IoT edge gateway and came to know that this gateway support Device->Cloud messaging but not Cloud->Device messaging. So I want to know whether we can establish a bidirectional communication by using this Azure IoT edge gateway.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cloud to device communication is possible from Azure IoT Hub to the leaf devices connected via the Azure IoT Edge device gateway. Direct communication is not possible.

1. You need to first ensure that the proper port number is opened.
2. You will need to create a module to handle the messages coming in from IoT Hub and properly identify the leaf device for which it belongs.
3. Deploy the module to the edge device (gateway)
4. Refer the link below for getting help

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d#:~:text=This%20app%20connects%20to%20your,then%20receives%20its%20delivery%20acknowledgment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d#:%7E:text=This%20app%20connects%20to%20your,then%20receives%20its%20delivery%20acknowledgment).

Comment: the device is non-programmable I am only allowed to change the IP address in the device so for this type of device it is possible for the cloud to device communication.

Comment: I understand that the end device may.not be programmable. I was talking about the module creation for the edge device, which acts as the gateway device. I am sure the edge device can be programmed being a gateway device. Can you please let me know what edge device you are using?

Comment: I am planning to use the server as an edge device